# unity3d c# dynamically add transparent texture

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I try to add transparent .png texture dynamically to a gameObject (aio) but it is not working, the texture remains plain.

```
            Texture2D ttr = 
             new Texture2D (512,512,
                TextureFormat.ARGB32,false);

            ttr =
                 (Texture2D)
                   Resources.Load
                    ("img/ttr/cub/blk");

             aio.GetComponent<Renderer>().
              material.mainTexture=
               ttr;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I have to add a shader type to the Renderer:

```
            Texture2D ttr = 
             new Texture2D
              (512,512,
                TextureFormat.ARGB32,false);
            ttr =
                 (Texture2D)
                   Resources.Load
                    ("img/ttr/cub/tpr2");
             aio.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().
              material.shader= 
               Shader.
                Find("Transparent/Diffuse");
             aio.GetComponent<Renderer>().
              material.mainTexture=
               ttr;
```